# ifdef debug leads to warning C4100 in release build

Tags: c++

i have the following code snippet:

```
void MyExampleMethod(string errorMessage)
{
  #ifdef _DEBUG
     MessageBox(errorMessage);
  #endif

//do something in release and debug
}
```

When i build this in release im getting C4100 because the variable errorMessage is unused. Does anybody know a nice way to avoid this warning without suppressing it?

Comment: You can use `[[maybe_unused]]` attribute.

Comment: `(void)errorMessage;` somewhere where it is unused.